# export unsigned ipa with fastlane/gym

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I'm trying to export an **unsigned** ipa with fastlane.
My gym configuration so far:

```
  desc "Archive ipa"
  lane :archive
    gym(
      workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace",
      scheme: "my_scheme",
      configuration: "Release",
      output_name: "my_app" ,
      output_directory: "$HOME/releases/",
      archive_path: "/tmp/builds/my_app",
      xcargs: "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO",
      clean: true,
    )
  end
```

Creating the archive works fine, but the `exportArchive` command fails:

```
+ xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/0z/g96lg8p16m12xmlhsqhymqd40000gn/T/gym_config20160815-92249-18a1h2g.plist -archivePath /tmp/builds/my_app.xcarchive -exportPath /var/folders/0z/g96lg8p16m12xmlhsqhymqd40000gn/T/gym_output20160815-92249-11hxnye
2016-08-15 13:42:06.531 xcodebuild[92599:6056507] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/0z/g96lg8p16m12xmlhsqhymqd40000gn/T/appConfig_2016-08-15_13-42-06.529.xcdistributionlogs'.
2016-08-15 13:42:07.724 xcodebuild[92599:6056507] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fc7bc578e90>: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive}
error: exportArchive: No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive

Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive}

** EXPORT FAILED **
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XCode 7 export process (that supports app slimming and bit code) does not support unsigned IPAs as far as I'm aware.

If you pass in `use_legacy_build_API: true` to gym, it should work as expected.

Comment: This no longer works with Xcode 8 as the PackageApplication script that gym relied on for legacy builds has been removed.

Comment: True, though slight correction: It no longer works in Xcode _8.3_